# How to exit an async method early that wraps an awaitable method?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

My class is wrapping `TcpListener` and I'm trying to update it to use modern `async` language.

It throws up the question what to do if a method should exit early. If this is the old code:

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        if (tcp != null)
          tcp.Connect(config.IPAddress, config.Port);
    }
```

Then I start with something like this:

```
    public Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        if (tcp != null)
          { ???? }    
        return tcp.ConnectAsync(config.IPAddress, config.Port);
    }
```

But in the condition `tcp==null` what should I return? Is there some "null awaitable"?

I also am unsure if my method should be designated `async` or not in this case where I am wrapping another method - I am sure I do *not* want to `await` the called method. This compiles but I do not think it is right:

```
    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        if (tcp != null)
            return;

        await tcp.ConnectAsync(config.IPAddress, config.Port);
    }
```

Comment: `Task.CompletedTask`? See also `Task.FromResult`. From the caller's point of view there's no difference between an `async` method and a non`-async` method: the only difference here is whether any exceptions are thrown directly, or wrapped up in the `Task` that's returned. Your `async` version is perfectly fine, and is recommended by some because of its exception-returning behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a completed task:

```
public Task ConnectAsync()
{
    if (tcp == null)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    return tcp.ConnectAsync(config.IPAddress, config.Port);
}
```

`Task.CompletedTask` is also a singleton instance, so there is no additional overhead if this method is called regularly.

You could also write your method as `async` and return nothing at all:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync()
{
    if (tcp != null)
    {
        await tcp.ConnectAsync(config.IPAddress, config.Port);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the extra `await` is not a problem that it ends up introducing an extra `Task` (`await ConnectAsync()` involves 2 `await` tasks).

Comment: @ Mr.Boy Yes, for this example you could go with the first option which would prevent a second `Task` from being created, however, if the method was expanded to include code that could throw an exception, then it would be better to use `async` / `await`. This is because async methods place exceptions on their returned `Task` rather than throwing them directly.